# Experience Editor does not work properly for pages with certain names in sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, content-editor, experience-editor

While creating a new page for my site, I found out that pages named "t", "u", "n" or "o" can not be edited properly in the Experience Editor.
If I try to open the Experience Editor for these pages, it either does not open the Editor or it opens the Editor, but adding any component causes an error message.

For eg: I created a page named "t" -> opened experience editor -> tried to add components -> causes error message "an error occurred" to appear in experience editor but when I go to Content editor that component is added.

Next I tried changing the display name of the item to "test" and kept item name as it is "t"  -> tried to add components in experience editor -> causes same error message to appear in experience editor but when I go to Content editor that component is added.

Next I tried to change item name to "tr" instead of "t" and kept display name as "test" ->  tried to add components in experience editor -> component is added successfully in experience editor as well as content editor.

As a workaround we can add a string to the item name, but I am not able to figure out why is it happening for these letters. Did someone encounter this issue? Actually I need to add glossary in my website so i have to create item names by single letters only from A to Z so need help on this.

Comment: All those work fine for me on Sitecore 8, Update 6. You should try on a clean install of Sitecore to make sure the problem is not related to your code.

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: Tried these combinations in Sitecore.NET 8.0 (rev. 150427) and they work fine in  Experience Editor and able to add more components wherever I want. Have you tried what @Łukasz Skowroński is suggesting?

Comment: Hello, I am using Sitecore .NET rev 150812 and still encountering the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How your site configuration looks like? Do you have "languageEmbedding" set to "asNeeded"? If the answer is yes - try to change it to "never" or "always". 
This behavior occurs because sitecore tries to find language in your url.

There is also another options - do you use wildcards inside your structure? sometimes experience editor can't decide - load wildcard or item from structure. 
The solution is move wildcard into other directory.

Comment: Hi, there are no wildcards in my structure. Also, this issue is occurring on pre-prod and prod environments. It is not occurring on my local machine and development environment. I compared config files of all the environments, there are no changes related to languageEmbedding property. The setting is same across all the environments. Is there any other property which i can check?

Comment: @NatashaBatra well in this situation I probably would do following steps:  
1) open a browser console in experience editor view  
2) check ajax request made by experience editor ( if error occured - there should be visible description )  
3) if error wouldn't say nothing to you, please copy-paste it here